# Query the exact partition when table is hash-partitioned

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, partitioning, database-partitioning

When I want to query a single partition I usually use something like that:

```
Select * from t (partition p1)
```

But when you have to query it in your pl/sql code it comes to using `execute immediate` and hard-parse of the statement.

Okay, for RANGE-partitioned table (let it be SOME_DATE of `date` type) I can workaround it like

```
Select * from t where some_date <= :1 and some_date > :2
```

Assuming `:1` and `:2` stand for partition bonds.

Well, as for LIST-partitioned table I can easily specify the exact value of my partition key field like

```
Select * from t where part_key = 'X'
```

And what about HASH-partitioning? For example, I have a table partitioned by `hash(id)` in 16 partitions. And I have 16 jobs each handling its own partition. So I have to use it like that

```
Select * from t (partition p<n>)
```

Question is: can I do it like this for example

```
Select * from t where hash(id) = :1
```

To enforce partition pruning take the whole n-th partition?

It's okay when you have just 16 partitions but in my case I have composite partitioning (date + hash(id)), so every time job handles a partition it's always a new `sql_id` and it ends up in quick shared pool growth

Comment: I'm not clear what the issue is. `where part_key = 'X' and subpart_key = 'Pie'` will take you to the exact subpartition. Or you could use `subpartition for` syntax but then you are back to hard parsing.

Comment: Keep in mind that partitioning is intended to help queries that process a large percentage of rows from a table, whereas indexes are intended to help queries that process a small percentage of rows.  If you're worried about filling up the shared pool with too many queries, that implies you're using partitions to process small amounts of data.  You might want to consider an index strategy instead.  Or, if the overall process is working on most of the data, try to combine queries and process a lot of data at one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears [Oracle internally uses the `ora_hash` function](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/ora_hash-function/) (at least since 10g) to assign a value to a partition.  So you could use that to read all the data from a single partition.  Unfortunately, though, since you'd be running a query like

```
select *
  from t
 where ora_hash( id, 9 ) = 6
```

to get all the data in the 6th of 8 hash partitions, I'd expect Oracle to have to read every partition in the table (and compute the hash on every `id`) because the optimizer isn't going to be smart enough to recognize that your expression happens to map exactly to its internal partitioning strategy.  So I don't think you'd want to do this to split data up to be processed by different threads.

Depending on what those threads are doing, would it be possible to use Oracle's built-in parallelism instead (potentially incorporating things like parallelizable pipelined table functions if you're doing ETL processing).  If you tell Oracle to use 16 parallel threads and your table has 16 partitions, Oracle will internally almost certainly do the right thing.

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation! That `almost certainly` thing scares me. Can I control it somehow? Like split threads among partitions? The second reason I don't want parallel DML is that I would have to set higher `undo_retention` to ensure that transaction succeeds. In case of parallel jobs it gets easier cause each partition is handled by its own job so there are lesser data than when you DML the whole table

Comment: @Roman - I say "almost certainly" because you'd need to look at the query plan your system generates for your query to confirm that it's doing what we'd expect.  I don't see a way to force parallel query to break up the data in a way that you want but I'd really expect Oracle to do that better than a human anyway.

Comment: Too late probably but you could add a virtual column that performs the ora_hash and move the table to be a list partition for all the possible results of ora_hash. If you select on that then oracle will hit the specific subpartitions only.

Comment: @SebastianPiu thanks for answer. I did it exactly like you've written.